# All processes crashing suddenly

Tags: crashes, motorola-moto-g2

So, for the 5th time, my Moto G2 (2014) started crashing all android core processes: acore, gapps, etc; over and over again, you press the "OK" button, it crashes again immediately.

Resetting the phone won't fix it.

The last 4 times I always had to make a factory reset, EVERY 3 MONTHS. I can't find any info regardless that issue, and no I don't download anything other than the Google Play Store. I do, however, use my phone as a debugging device for apps I create, since I'm a developer.

These crashes always happen after updating apps on google play. If I could take SS I would, but my phone won't work at all. There's infinite popups saying "com.android.acore has stopped", "com.google.process.gapps has stopped", and it never ends;  and then it start crashing the rest of the apps (Instagram, Facebook, Whatsapp, etc).

**Note**: I am **not** running lollipop since they didn't make a proper update for lollipop on the xt1063; they only made a rom with memory leak that needs to be reseted every 6 hours. I'm running **4.4.4**.

Please I **beg** for some help, I am already tired of factory reseting my phone every 5 times.

Comment: Did you consider the idea of switching to a custom ROM? This may really be your best choice, if you're unable to update to Lollipop due to the poor quality of the stock firmware.

Comment: Time to [load CM](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=titan) and let go of this miserable situation. Anyhow. Have you observed, after which particular app update does the system go haywire? I mean, it could be that a system app (possibly a Google app) is always updated by Play Store which triggers  this series of crashes. // What does logcat say?